# Is this well known, and if so what it is called?

Tags: differential

Given the Exact Differential
$$M(x,y) \, dx + N(x,y) \, dy = 0\tag 1$$

I noticed that at least in Mathematica, the solution $\phi(x,y)$ can be found via solving the following differential equation from manipulation of $(1)$.

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} \equiv \frac{-M(x,y)}{N(x,y)} $$
I'm Standard Form, dropping $(x,y)$,
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{M}{N} \equiv 0$$
In Mathematica:

```
DSolve[y'[x]== -m[x,y[x]]/n[x,y[x]],y[x],x]
```

Is this commonly known, used, and if so, what is it called? Thank you all very much. 
I am starting to feel as though this should be in the Mathematica SE. If others believe so, please vote to move.

Comment: What you say is of course true, however the right hand side is not necessarily easy to integrate.  Try a simple example such as $N=xy$ and $M=x+y^2$.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but, for example, after checking a hand solution via standard methods typing this into Mathematica will give you an easy way to check the solution to the differential, as Mathematica can't solve a difference of equation in the form stated in [1] above

Comment: Is this true? My comment above didn't have a question my apologies

Comment: I could see that Mathematica users (and perhaps other CAS users) might find it useful, but there is no name for it even though it is well known.

Comment: Okay thank you @PaulSundheim, want to turn your comment into an answer? It hits the nail on the head perfectly.

Comment: Ok. Done. See below. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could see that Mathematica users (and perhaps other CAS users) might find it useful, but there is no name for it even though it is well known.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to up vote. But I clicked the check mark thing. Thanks again.